# boundary at infinity of $\mathbb{H}^2$

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

In hyperbolic geometry what does it mean when they say the boundary at infinity of $\mathbb{H}^2$? The only idea I came up with was a horizontal line to represent the horizon and to lines meeting at a point on that line, but they are not actually intersecting at the horizon line. The road goes off to infinity. Or do I have the wrong idea here?

Comment: It might refer to the points on the boundary of the Poincaré disk model. Could you provide some more context of when "they" speak about this?

Comment: I quote "One of the central objects in the study of hyperbolic geometry is the boundary at infinity of $\mathbb{H}^2$".

Comment: Who do you quote?

Comment: Benson Farb and Dan Margalit

Answer (score 2):

Independent of any model, we may say that the points at $\infty$ are the equivalence classes of half-lines in $\mathbb H$ under the relation $\sim$, where $L\sim L'$ if and only if as $p\in L$ goes to infinity (away from the endpoint), the distance from $p$ to $L'$ goes to $0$. As an example, in the half-plane model, two vertical half-lines are similar under $\sim$.

Comment: ... if they're pointing up rather than down.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, you’re absolutely right.