# What the boundary of the disc in Poincaré disk model exactly is by a geometric point of view?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology

Poincaré disk model is defined in a open disc, and the boundary of the disc represent **something** infinitely distant. But what the **"something"** exactly is?

How to topologically or geometrically extend the open disc in Poincaré disk model into a closed disc? Intuitively I think it is related with compactification of $H^2$. Is this a correct idea?

P.S. As some friend pointed to me, this should be related with conformal infinite or conformal boundary, and conformal compactification, ref https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4703 but is that the whole answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary of the Poincaré disk is most definitely *not* a topological object.

It is inherently a geometric object, and it is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653805/boundary-at-infinity-of-mathbbh2/653857#653857).

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horocycle#/media/File:Horocycle_normals.svg) is a picture of single equivalence class of rays in the Poincare disc model, i.e. all lines in the Poincare disc sharing a common point at infinity.

Comment: Thanks. Agree with you, I am not sure it is a topological object. But could you give some references to elaborate more? Thanks again.

Comment: Is the relationship of ~ a cofinal relationship? So we can treat an element of the equivalent class as all the lines share a final point. But what is the whole structure of the equivalent classes?

Comment: I've added a link to a picture of an equivalence class.